# Is it possible to remove an empty white page due to inserting a too large picture?

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, blank-page

From searching here, I have understood than when inserting a picture too large for the available space, even on an empty page, the picture will be put on the next page. However, leaving a page empty seems… not very usefull, as the next page will also be too small. Is it possible to prevent the insertion of an empty page?

Here is a code example:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,inner=0cm,outer=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
{\includegraphics[width=1.1\textwidth]{C:/OSM/CarnetRando/Cartes/1_Thann_Nord.png}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I cannot, right now, check with a TeX compiler, but if I remember well LaTeX sometimes inserts a `\write-1{}` at the beginning of a page: that causes the `\topskip` glue, that follows, to become a legal breakpoint for the page builder.  Try adding `\nobreak` before `\includegraphics` (while still in vertical mode).

Comment: Thanks for the answer… but I'm not sure I've understood everything. Switching to \nobreak\includegraphics does not solve the problem.

Comment: @JB_ It does not make much sense to add a picture that's bigger than the available space. If your aim is to add a background picture, then there are better ways to do it. Can you explain?

Comment: On second thought, `\nobreak` won’t work: it will be discarded when moved from the recent contributions to the current page because the latter doesn’t contain any box yet.  Mmh, this one looks pretty tough… :-)

Comment: @egreg Actually, the picture is the size of the page, but I add some additional objects using \stackinset that makes the whole object very slightly larger than the page. Reducing the whole is not a solution as it would introduce white borders around the page. (Another solution would be to trim/clip the whole, but I do not really like it either…)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppressing addition of blank page before figure when wrapping long JPEG image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287875/suppressing-addition-of-blank-page-before-figure-when-wrapping-long-jpeg-image) I believe the accepted answer there to be the best (simplest) answer for this problem.

Comment: Another option would be to somehow merge all the similar questions around the problem: the blank page before `\includegraphics`. Still, each their MWE might be slightly different from another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it, but there are better ways to do it:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,inner=0cm,outer=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup
\maxdepth=\maxdimen % accept any depth
\raisebox{\topskip-\height}[0pt][\height-\topskip]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][l]{%
    \includegraphics[width=2\textwidth,height=2\textheight]{example-image}%
  }%
}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

I emulated a very big picture by setting the width and height to twice the dimensions. What you need to do is making TeX see dimensions compatible with the text block size.

[image]

Maybe your aim is to fill the first page with a picture; in this case `atbegshi` is much easier to use.

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{atbegshi}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginShipoutNext{%
  \AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \put(0,0){%
      \raisebox{-\height}{%
        \includegraphics[width=2\paperwidth,height=2\paperheight]{example-image}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\clearpage % produce an empty page

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Playing around a bit with your code made it work, thanks! I understand that \raisebox is not really a nice/safe solution, but when not much else works…

Comment: @JB_ I tried to interpret your wish with a different solution

Comment: Of course, hiding the real dimensions of the image solves the problem.  But I’m left with my doubt: is there a means to inhibit the page break at the `\topskip` glue in a situation like this?  I mean, given the presence of a whatsit at the beginning of the current page, and with an overly tall box being contributed as the first box on the current page itself.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti That's something I discussed with Frank a couple of months ago in chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/41?m=20903287#20903287

Comment: Actually, the problem happens not only at the first page, but also later in the document, so the \atbegingshi is not a solution here. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: @JB_ You just need to issue another `\AtBeginShipoutNext` command.

Comment: I see.  As it seems, at some point Frank Mittelbach suggested to add a `\nobreak` after the `\write` in the code of `\document`, but, as I remarked above, that penalty would never make it into the “current page” as long as it contains no boxes; and, on the other hand, as soon as you do add a box (or a rule), the `\topskip` glue is triggered.  I see no way out of this dilemma, so I’d rather conclude that the break cannot be inhibited in any way.

Comment: In a similar situation, your solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287910/3463 worked for me, too: `\vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-\topskip}` before the `\includegraphics`! Thanks for that magic! As I'm just putting one image per page, my complete code introducing each image has become: `\newpage\noindent\vspace*{\fill}\vspace{-\topskip}\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{...jpg}` and there are even no warnings about overfull boxes. And I also put a `\centering` at the beginning of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is because of the paragraph indentation.

You can overcome this by issuing the command `\noindent`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=0cm,bottom=0cm,inner=0cm,outer=0cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{demo}
\end{document}
```

Note that I'm using `demo` because I don't have your picture, but you should be fine as long as you keep in mind that the width of the picture should be the same as the `\linewidth`.

[image]

Comment: Hello, unfortunately, this does not work : the picture IS larger than the page, in both dimensions. (It is actually the same size as the page, but some \stackinset makes it larger, in both dimensions). I'm also trying to clip the whole so that it fits, but do not really like the method.