# Suppressing addition of blank page before figure when wrapping long JPEG image

Tags: graphics, includegraphics, blank-page

I have the following LaTeX file, whose sole purpose is to wrap a JPEG file. This file does not convert well to PDF, so I'm using this unorthodox technique to convert it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\centering\includegraphics[height=650pt]{foo.jpg}
\end{document}
```

This produces a PDF file including the document, but it first includes a blank page, and thus produces a 2 page document, rather than a 1 page document. How do I get rid of this blank page? Using `\textheight` instead of `650pt` as an argument to `\includegraphics`makes the 
problem go away, but I'd prefer the larger size I get from using `650pt`.

Here is the relevant information from the log file.

```
<foo.jpg, id=1, 162.6075pt x 1165.35374pt>
File: foo.jpg Graphic file (type jpg)

<use foo.jpg>
Package pdftex.def Info: foo.jpg used on input line 14.
(pdftex.def)             Requested size: 90.6998pt x 650.0pt.
 [1

]
Overfull \vbox (100.0pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

 [2 <./foo.jpg>] (./foo.aux) )
```

I'd prefer to not make the actual document public.
Therefore the code above is not a MWE.
However, if anyone has tips on how to create a dummy JPEG
of the same size, let me know.

Comment: Why don't you use the `standalone` clss?

Comment: I even don't get any overfull warnings, but still get an extra blank page before `\includegraphics` at the beginning of the document. Here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246734/3463 it was told that the `\topskip` glue at the beginning of a page (that causes this) is unavoidable. What a pity!

Comment: Almost duplicate of [includegraphics - Prevent page break of full-text-area graphic inclusion - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261786/prevent-page-break-of-full-text-area-graphic-inclusion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to center the image on the normal output page (US Letter or A4), just do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{empty}
\flushbottom

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\vspace{-\topskip}
\centering
\includegraphics[height=650pt]{example-image-9x16}

\vspace{\fill}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, egreg. That works well. Can you add some commentary explaining why what you are doing works? Also, I checked out `\flushbottom`, which I'm not familiar with. But https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#g_t_005cflushbottom says "It makes all later pages the same height, stretching the vertical space where necessary to fill out the page." What does this do in this context?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's just for safety; to be honest, I didn't even try without it.

Answer (score 4):

If the image won't come to `\textheight` then `\textheight` must go to the image:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\textheight=650pt
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\centering\includegraphics[height=650pt]{example-image-10x16}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Another approach could be enclose the image in a smaller box that fit in the text area.

Comment: Would you mind setting the textheight using the interface from geometry, or at least use LaTeX syntax?

Comment: @Johannes_B I do not why, but is not the exactly same that use `\usepackage[textheight=650pt]{geometry}`. This way is more centered.   With respect the LaTeX syntax, I do not use `\setlength{\textheight}{650pt}` because a very good reason (for me): lazyness.

Comment: Lazyness might be the reason for having `\bf` and friends still around.

Comment: @Johannes_B Probably many still do in the privacy `:D`

Comment: @Fran if Johannes worries about your lack of latex syntax, I'm not sure what he'll say about mine:-)

Comment: Hi Fran. Nice out of the box thinking. Thank you. But wouldn't it be better to just write `height=\textheight` instead?

Comment: Also, where do you use the `geometry` package?

Comment: @FaheemMitha without `geometry`  change the `\oddsidemargin`  (even without options)  and then the left margin is wider. With respect to use a relative height, in general is better to adapt the image size to the document layout , but in this case  you asked maintain an absolute length,  so ... why change it?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the page size to be that of an image and you don't want to set up fonts etc then you don't really need a class at all:

```
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\setbox0\hbox{\includegraphics{example-image-10x16.jpg}}
\hoffset-1in
\voffset-1in
\pdfpageheight\ht0
\pdfpagewidth\wd0
\shipout\box0
\stop
```

Comment: Hi, David. The image still needs rescaling, though.

Comment: @FaheemMitha more useful to scale the image while it is being used than while it is being made.