# My document's page begins with 2 after removing the blank page

Tags: numbering, blank-page, page, remove

My document was having a blank page at the beginning. I removed it using:

```
\usepackage{atbegshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/atbegshi
\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutNext{\AtBeginShipoutDiscard}}
```

This code worked to remove the blank page, but the 1st page is numbered as 2. Please help!

Comment: you don't give many clues to allow someone to help. You could simply use `\setcounter{page}{1}` but the whole construct is probably just hiding the symptoms of an error elsewhere. LaTeX documents do not normally start with a blank page so if you are getting one it may be better to fix the code that is forcing that rather than add complicated code to remove the spurious page. Please always provide a complete small document that shows the problem.

Comment: you perhaps have something very large on the first page which force LaTeX to move it to the second page. Try with \enlargethispage{2cm} to give it more room.

Comment: As mentioned above, please write a minimal working example. See [link](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/250119) for more details what it means. — Although a guess is  [graphics - Suppressing addition of blank page before figure when wrapping long JPEG image - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287875/suppressing-addition-of-blank-page-before-figure-when-wrapping-long-jpeg-image)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, whatever is going on in your document, you can always reset the page counter

```latex
\setcounter{page}{1}
```

... even though this is more like a quick fix only and doesn't tackle the root of the problem.